Can I join a masters program in Computer Science with a degree in Information Science?
Is it possible for me to enroll in a master's program in Computer Science if I hold a bachelor's degree in Information Science?
I am interested in understanding the prerequisites and any additional requirements that may be necessary for someone with my academic background to successfully transition into a graduate program focused on Computer Science.

Only the institution offering the master's program can answer that question. Maybe they have a statement on prerequisites that covers your bachelor's degree, or maybe they decide case by case comparing your degree with their expectations.

This depends on country at least and probably on the requirements of a particular institution. It can't be answered as is, other than to say "Yes, somewhere". It is a local question to be answered locally.

What is also important is your work experience since graduating. Do you have relevant computing/IT experience since graduating with your bachelor degree? Masters are often taken by people who want to change their careers or validate their experience. So not everybody on a master's program will always have a bachelor degree in the same field.

I got into (and completed) a Master's degree with a political science undergrad degree. Sure, it's possible. I suggest rephrasing the question to focus on the second paragraph rather than the first: "what are the steps I'd likely need to take?" rather than "can this be done?" which is hopefully self-evidently "yes". Please provide plenty of context on your programming and CS background (if any).
